# Why do we use "accessible to" instead of "accessible from"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, adjectives

I wonder why we use "accessible to" as a meaning of "can be accessed from", for example, "How to Make Your Blog **Accessible to** Blind Reader".

It makes more sense to me when using 'accessible from'. Is it wrong to use 'accessible from'?

Comment: "Accessible from" sounds like a _place_ or something that you can access it from. "The back garden is accessible from the kitchen."

Comment: Yeah, *[accessible from](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=accessible_ADJ+vcomp+from_PREP)* is more related to a location, place. But imho the question could be, why not *for* like for *available* [1 for](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=available_ADJ+vcomp+for_PREP) - [2 to](http://www.just-the-word.com/show_examples.pl?triple=available_ADJ+vcomp+to_PREP)

Comment: "Accessible from" means you can get to it from somewhere. "Accessible to" means that it can be got at by something.

Comment: So the question should have been: why don't we use _accessible by_ or _accessible for_.

Comment: https://lingohelp.me/preposition-after-adjective/accessible-to-by-for-from-in/

Answer (score 8):

> I wonder why we use "accessible to" as a meaning of "can be accessed from"...

Except, we don't. However, it can be used as a meaning of *can be accessed by*.

> How to make your blog accessible **to** blind readers.

This is correct as you are giving blind readers access *to* the blog.

> <strike>How to make your blog accessible **from** blind readers.</strike>

This implies that you can access your blog *from* blind readers! Not what the author had in mind, I imagine.

Some other examples:

> This building *is accessible to* wheelchair users.
>
> This building *can be accessed by* wheelchair users.
>
> This building *is accessible from* the west.
>
> This content *is only accessible to* subscribers.
>
> This content *can only be accessed by* subscribers.
>
> This content *is only accessible from* Internet Explorer.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase *accessible to* makes sense because it parallels the noun form, *access*, which routinely takes the preposition *to* when referring to the persons or things doing the accessing.

> Give access to people with passes.

The preposition *from* is used to describe geography that suggests a point of entry or origin.

> There is access from the street to that garden.

Note that the destination of the *access* still takes *to*.

The adjectival form accessible is handled similarly

> The garden is *accessible from* the street.
>   The garden will be *accessible to* those with passes.